# scatter in mpi [a very simple code]

Tags: c, mpi

Here is code of mpi scatter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>       

int a[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int b[1];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
    int rank;       

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank ==0){
        MPI_Scatter(a,1,MPI_INT,b,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("\n%d from rank=%d\n",b[0],rank);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I want output as follows:

> 1 from rank 0
>   2 from rank 1
>   3 from rank 2
>   ...

But I am getting

> 1 from rank 0
>   0 from rank 1
>   0 from rank 2
>   0 from rank 3
>   0 from rank 4
>   ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_Scatter()` is a collective operation, and hence it must be called by **all** the ranks of the communicator.

get rid of the `if (rank == 0)` and you will be fine.

Note that in your example, the `a` send buffer is small enough and does not cause any hang.